# Issue with Datagrid TotalRows and Databind()

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, datagrid

I have issue with the following code

```
e.TotalRows = data.Count(); //getting exception
Jqgrid1.DataSource = data.Skip((e.NewPageIndex - 1) * Jqgrid1.PagerSettings.PageSize).Take(Jqgrid1.PagerSettings.PageSize);
Jqgrid1.DataBind();
```

**Error decription on browser is**

```
The full-text query parameter for Fulltext Query String is not valid.
```

**Description:**

```
 An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
 Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it 
 originated in the code.
```

**Exception Details:**

```
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
   The full-text query parameter for Fulltext Query String is not valid.
```

I am using `.Net 4`. 
My connection string is fine as I can log in as **Admin** and view other pages.

Does anyone know how to achieve this in asp.net??

Comment: Is data is an object of `DataTable` ? and under which event you have that code written ?

Comment: @yogi Yes, it is declared as var **data = <some SQL Query to get the data from DB>**

Comment: Its hard to track the error from this code only, but I guess most probably the SQL query you are forming to select data from database is not right (if you are doing that). it would be easier if you could share some more of your code.

Comment: where you have specified the code? is it in RowDataBound event?

Comment: It was something similar to what yogi said. But the Linq query was right, **the problem was nvarchar(256) QSL data type and nvarchar(4000) datatype mismatch**. 

Thanks for the answers and the effort.